# Get activities instances which are hosted within TabHost

Tags: android-activity, xamarin.android

I want to place some activities inside a TabHost as tabs and to access them later.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.FirstView);

TabHost.TabSpec spec;

sspec = TabHost.NewTabSpec ("tab1");
spec.SetIndicator ("tab1");
spec.SetContent (new Intent (this, typeof(LiveView)));
TabHost.AddTab (spec);

spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec ("tab2");
spec.SetIndicator ("tab2");
spec.SetContent (new Intent (this, typeof(DetailsView)));
TabHost.AddTab (spec);
}

public void Show(Fragment frag)
{
      var activityFromTab = ... // Get activity from tab widget
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I could not understand what you are trying to do, you are passing, What Fragment you are passing as paramenter then?

Comment: It does not matter what Fragment I am passing, its type can vary. I need to get a reference to an Activity object (not intent) and pass this reference to another object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved that by using

```
TabRootView currentRootView = (TabRootView)this.LocalActivityManager.GetActivity (currentRootTag);
```

I add clid's intent into the TabHost of parent activity and mark this intent by the tag (string constant). Then use the tag and the LocalActivityManager property of the parent to fing the target.